# Making a Contravariant Object

Tags: scala, contravariance

I'm trying to create a class that's contravariant:

```
class ContraObj[-T] {
  var item: T = _                 // initialize `item` to "some" T value
  def replace(t: T) = (item = t) 
}
```

But the following compile-time error occurs:

```
[error] .../ContraObj.scala:4: contravariant type T occurs in covariant 
   position in type => T of method item
[error]   var item: T = _
[error]       ^
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Contravariant types will be inputs, never outputs.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: Some more background can be found at Twitter's Scala School, starting at "Contravariance seems strange. When is it used? Somewhat surprising!", http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance

Comment: @KevinMeredith, you have to understand that functions are covariant on their inputs, but contravariant on outputs. Look at [Function1](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Function1.scala) for example. Also, relate this with [wheaties](http://stackoverflow.com/users/178060/wheaties)' [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21866270/205936).

Comment: @KevinMeredith "Why" is really beyond knowledge. If you think of `Function1`, and what it means for its covariant and contravariant parameters, it makes sense. I'm pretty sure set theory or category theory and some kind of logic is can explain the why, but I never looked into that myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to think about what contravariance means. That is, what does it imply and what constraints will result because of it. Hence,

```
trait Foo[-T]{
  def stuff(t: T): T
}
```

Now think about what this means in the following context:

```
def action(that: Foo[Int]) = that.stuff(1)
```

and if I pass it a `Foo[Any]`. Does this then mean that if I expect the following definition to hand me back an `Int` that it will suceed?

```
def action(that: Foo[Int]): Int = that.stuff(1)
```

It can't, can it? That's because what you've defined is a function and functions have as their signature `Function[-T, +R]` and you're trying to define it as `Function[-T, -T]`.

Comment: So, in your example, `def action(that: Foo[Int]): Int = that.stuff(1)`, `Int` is an instance of `T`, which is contravariant. `action` is defined as `Function[-T, -T]` since `Int` is both the type parameter of `Foo[]` and the `return type`? I got it to compile with - https://gist.github.com/kman007us/9094483, but why would I want `AnyVal` - it's not type-safe, no?

Comment: @KevinMeredith In your example, you'd actually want `action` to have the following: `def action[R](that: Foo[Int, R]): R = that.stuff(1)` to capture what you're looking for. There `R` can vary any way you want and should be inferred from the type system.

Comment: Thanks, @wheaties. I've progressed with your answer, but I still can't put together 1-2 sentences why it makes sense for `Function` to have `[-R, +T]`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I know there is a good theoretical reason why this is the case (the arguments are acceptors.) I've never really given it much thought beyond the "this just makes sense" line of reasoning. Good question to ask.

Comment: Martin Odersky gives a great explanation of why `Function` is `[-R, +T]` in the Coursera *Functional Programming Principles in Scala* lecture on Variance (https://class.coursera.org/progfun-2012-001/lecture/83)